# Unit Test protected method of an abstract class

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, nunit, abstract-class

I'm trying to write a unit test to test a protected method in an abstract class.  I've tried writing a test class that inherits from the abstract class, but when I instantiate the test class the base abstract class attempts to connect to an Oracle database and fails which doesn't allow me to test the protected method I'm interested in.  The abstract class cannot be modified.

How can I directly unit test a protected method in this abstract class?

Here is snippet of what I tried with reflection.

```
Type type = typeof(AbstractClass);
BindingFlags eFlags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
MethodInfo myMethod = type.GetMethod("ProtectedMethod", eFlags);
object[] arguments = new object[] { _myDs };
myMethod.Invoke(type, arguments);
_myDs = (DataSet)arguments[0];
```

Comment: Why do you need to use reflection when you can just create a subclass? If your basemethod connects to a database then you have to mock this. Can you extract the database-connecting to a different class?

Comment: I already mentioned that when I use a derived class of the abstract class, when the derived class is instantiated the abstract class will attempt to access an Oracle database and fail, which causes the whole unit test to fail.  So...  How can I just get to the protected method that is inside of the abstract class?  No I cannot extract the database-connecting to a different class.  It follows CSLA standards.

Comment: @Shar1er80: If you're having an issue like that, does that method *really* belong in that class? If you want to test it without the connection, that implies that it has a separate responsibility. Consider moving it to a different class.

Comment: It makes no sense for the base class to access a database upon instantiation, and if you can't change the way it accesses the database, then that class is far too tightly-coupled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is **doable**, but please note there may be couple of serious problems with your code:

- Constructor shouldn't perform any business logic.
- Your abstract class should not know about database type (Dependency Inversion Principle).
- Is your abstract class have more responsibilities? If yes, move them to separate classes / projects (Single Responsibility Principle).
- You shouldn't unit test non-public API.

Here's a recipe:

- First, create a fake instance of your abstract class.
- Then, call `FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject` for getting instance of the class without calling constructor.
- After that, you can use reflection for invoking `ProtectedMethod`.

By that, you are able to test `ProtectedMethod`:

- Without calling constructor.
- Without modifying abstract class.

And here is an example code:

```
class AbstractClassFake : AbstractClass { }

[Test]
public void Test()
{
    // Arrange:
    var abstractClassFake = (AbstractClassFake)FormatterServices
        .GetUninitializedObject(typeof(AbstractClassFake));

    MethodInfo method = abstractClassFake.GetType()
        .GetMethod("ProtectedMethod",
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    object[] arguments = new object[] { myDs };

    // Act:
    object val = method.Invoke(abstractClassFake, new[] { myDs });

    // Assert:
    // TODO: Your assertion here
}
```

Comment: hey man , I am watching your code and I have troubles understanding how the reflection works and what exactly is `myDs` .Also I have errors while trying to make the reflection. `abstractClassFake.GetType() is  throwing Error : An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property : object.GetType()` Could you explain a bit more whats going on here cause it seems that your code is really good and seems to me it is clean and readable from all others I've seen so far about this topic. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello. `myDs` variable is not initialized here. Author doesn't initialize that, so I assume it is either a field or a parameter. Besides, I would suggest to avoid such tests at all costs. This code demonstrates that it is possible to resolve the problem stated, but it also shows that testable code should be, most probably, redesigned. Please let me know if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 1):

Compromise.

Say you have:

```
public abstract class CanNeverChange
{
    public CanNeverChange()
    {
        //ACK!  connect to a DB!!  Oh No!!
    }

    protected abstract void ThisVaries();

    //other stuff
}

public class WantToTestThis : CanNeverChange
{
    protected override void ThisVaries()
    {
         //do something you want to test
    }
}
```

Change it to this:

```
public class WantToTestThis : CanNeverChange
{
    protected override void ThisVaries()
    {
         new TestableClass().DoSomethingYouWantToTest();
    }
}

public class TestableClass
{
    public void DoSomethingTestable()
    {
        //do something you want to test here instead, where you can test it
    }
}
```

Now you can test the behavior you want to test in `TestableClass`.  For the `WantToTestThis` class, compromise to the pressure of terrible legacy code, and don't test it.  Plugging in a testable thing with a minimal amount of untested code is a time honored strategy; I first heard of it from Michael Feather's book [Working Effectively with Legacy Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131177052).

Comment: Turns out editing the base abstract class was allowed and I ultimately did move the needed attributes and methods to an inner static class.  This caused minor changes to the caller of the methods and allowed the method I needed to be unit tested

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to break the class apart as the comments suggest.

**However**, if you would like to test it without changing the class very much, you could move the contents of the constructor into a virtual method:

```
public abstract class TheOracleOne
{
    protected virtual void Init()
    {
        // connection things
    }
}
```

And override in your derived class to do nothing:

```
public class TestClass : TheOracleOne
{
    protected override void Init()
    {
    }
}
```

This should skip the initialization that is taking place in the abstract class's constructor, allowing you to access the method normally on the derived class.

Comment: The base abstract class cannot be modified.

Comment: You should really only be testing code that you own and can modify. I guess I'd change my advice to: "don't test it" if that's the case.

Comment: Turns out editing the base abstract class was allowed and I ultimately did move the needed attributes and methods to an inner static class.  This caused minor changes to the caller of the methods and allowed the method I needed to be unit tested